# How to implement a doorbell for Google Home?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

How to implement a doorbell for Google Home? I'd like to have notification about pressing button. I have a few questoins:

- What kind of devise I need to implement? I don't see [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/) a corresponding type. Nearest is a switch, but I'm not sure that it's the same.
- How to send the event? In this case device should be active.
- How to set up an action to inform the whole home about the event? I'd like to speak some phrase or play sound on the Google Home device, and show a notification on Android phones. Does Android Home Assistant this feature, or I need to implement some sattelite applicaton?

Upd: As I understand, active notifications from Smart Home Devices are available, it was demonstrated on the Google I/O last year: https://youtu.be/h44p9IOaDwo?t=1685
Main question is how to do the same?

Comment: From what I can tell Google Home devices need a user prompt to activate,.So while your cloud service could identify a door bell ring, you would need your own app to generate a notification on a phone, but the Home would remain silent. See:[Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant) for you own voice actions.

Comment: Doorbells are not a publicly available device type, nor is the notification capabiity.

Comment: @NickFelker you can watch the link, I added to the question. somehow notifications are available. "Nest Hello" somehow is somehow integrating with Google Home. How? https://nest.com/doorbell/nest-hello/overview/

Comment: @MorrisonChang Notification was demonstrated on the Google IO, I added link to the question. How they implemented it?

Comment: This feature is not available for all developers to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a documentation about notificatoins. It's possible after getting permissions from user.

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications

But it allows up to 10 notifications per user per day, so during the birthday party you will have DoS.

Comment: The documentation link you reference still states `Note: Push notifications aren't currently supported on voice-activated speakers.` But as Google IO is still going on, documentation may change.